# Creating multipe columns in datagrid

Tags: wpf

I am looking for a help to bind data to datagrid of WPF.  I used to have two double arrays (t[] and a_scaled[]) and was able to bind these two arrays to datagrid by using the code below.  Each array was read from each text file.

Now I would like to modify this code to show mutiple arrays in multiple columns.  total number of arrays varies depending on what an enduser chooses.  For example, if an user selects 4 files from openfile dialog box, then four arrays from each file are shown on the datagrid.  Thanks for your help,

c#:

```
        private void openfile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            for (int i = 1; i < t.Length; i++)
            {
                tvsa.Add(new TvsA() { T = t[i], Acc = a_scaled[i] });
             }

             datagrid_accs.ItemsSource = tvsa;

        public class TvsA
         {
           public double T { get; set; }
           public double Acc { get; set; }
         }
```

XAML:

```
<Border BorderThickness="2" Margin="1">
        <StackPanel  Width="auto" Margin="10" >
            <Label Content="Target ARS Input:" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <ScrollViewer Height="auto" Width="auto" >
                <DataGrid Name="datagrid_tars" Width="auto"   AutoGenerateColumns="True" >
                </DataGrid>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
```

ps: I hope that someday I am able to help other people by answering questions they ask.

Comment: Please post your current code and XAML.

Comment: It sounds like you want more than one guideline.  OpenFiledialogs, reading text from files, setting up a datagrid, and binding/displaying strings in datagrid.. This question is too specific to ask without posting any of your own code, in my opinion.  Google those topics and you'll get your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> total number of arrays varies depending on what an enduser chooses.

So in other words, the challenge is to determine the number of columns at runtime.  There are multiple ways to do this:

1. Add Columns to DataGrid at runtime using code-behind.
2. Bind the ItemsSource to a [`DataTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
3. Bind the ItemsSource to a collection of a dynamic-typed object

Number 2, the DataTable, is probably the best approach for your scenario.  Simply add a column for each file/array, and then add each file's iteration to the table as a row.  There's an example of how to do this at the link above, but here's how you might do it (assuming a function that takes a list of arrays, and returns the DataTable) (untested):

```
DataTable GetTable(List<double[]> sourceArrays)
{
    // 1. add the columns

    DataTable table = new DataTable("table");
    for (int i=0 ; i<sourceArrays.Length ; i++)
        table.Add(new DataColumn());

    // 2. add the rows

    bool done = false;
    int rowNum = 0;
    while (!done)
    {
        var row = new List<double?>();
        for (int i=0 ; i<sourceArrays.Length ; i++)
            row.Add(rowNum < sourceArrays[i].Count ? sourceArrays[i][rownum] : null);
        if (row.All(col => !col.HasValue))
            done = true;
        else
            table.Rows.Add(row.ToArray());
        rowNum++;
    }
    return table;
}
```

Comment: thanks so much for your answer, I chose your suggestion no. 2. you are right. I made duplicate question I will delete one of them. sorry.